# Get all model names in datamapper sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

Is there a way to retrieve all the model names present in a database through DataMapper? It can be any DB sqlite, MySQL.

Currently I am using sqlite adapter to retrieve this information like this

```
adapter = DataMapper.repository(:default).adapter
tableinfo = adapter.select("select * from sqlite_master where type='table'")
```

I would like it to be independent of DB. But if not possible then at least a MySQL Equivalent.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I did some more research on DataMapper. Read it's documentation more closely and found this https://www.rubydoc.info/github/datamapper/dm-core/DataMapper/Model#descendants-class_method.

Basically what it states is:

```
DataMapper::Model.descendants # Return all models that extend the Model module
```

Not sure if it is the right way of doing things but, it has solved my query.

Thank you.